# SPARQL query restrict answers

Tags: netbeans, sparql, jena

hey im trying to get all the receipes that only contains some ingredients. For example if I have a receipe with tomato and bread and I only said that Im going to use tomate that receipe shouldnt show up. If I have any receipe with only this ingredient then it should show up. I did the following query:

```sql
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>`
PREFIX rec:<http://www.receta.org#>
SELECT reduced ?r 
WHERE { 
        ?x rdf:type rec:Receta .
        ?x rdfs:label ?r.
        ?x rec:Ingrediente rec:Tomato.
        ?x rec:Ingrediente ?i.
        FILTER (?i=rec:Tomato) 
}
```

But the problem is that it shows all the receipes that contains that ingredient and much more. How can I restrict this? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query

```sql
SELECT reduced ?r WHERE { 
  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta .
  ?x rdfs:label ?r.
  ?x rec:Ingrediente rec:Tomato.
  ?x rec:Ingrediente ?i.
  FILTER (?i=rec:Tomato) 
}
```

matches any recipe that has Tomato as some ingredient.  Using a filter with a constant value like that is the same as having written:

```sql
SELECT reduced ?r WHERE { 
  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta .
  ?x rdfs:label ?r.
  ?x rec:Ingrediente rec:Tomato.
}
```

Instead, you want to select recipes and remove those that have ingredients other than some set.  [AndyS's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27174334/1281433) mentions **filter not exist**, and that's a start.  Specifically, if you want to ensure that all the ingredients are, e.g., Tomato, Basil, and Cheese, then you would write a query like:

```sql
SELECT reduced ?r WHERE { 
  ?x rdf:type rec:Receta .
  ?x rdfs:label ?r.
  filter not exists {
    ?x rec:Ingrediente ?i
    filter( ?i not in (rec:Tomato, rec:Basil rec:Cheese) )
}
```

This finds all recipes, and then removes any which have an ingredient which is *not* one of the allowed ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `FILTER NOT EXISTS`.

So something like (depends of the exact nature of your data that isn't shown):

```
 WHERE { 
    ?x rdf:type rec:Receta .
    ?x rdfs:label ?r.
    FILTER NOT EXISTS {?x rec:Ingrediente rec:Tomato }
 }
```

which is all ?x, ?r where ?x does not have property/value "rec:Ingrediente rec:Tomato".